# SQL WEEK() gives different week number than date('W')

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The **SQL** fuction `Select WEEK(mydate) ...` is returning a week number different than the **PHP** function  `date('W',strtotime($mydate))`

Where `$mydate` is a String in the format `(Y-m-d h:i:s)` obtained by selecting the `mydate` variable on the **SQL** db.

It is just one week number of difference but I can't subtract because of the edge cases of 0 and 52, they get mixed up there.

I know `WEEK(mydate,3)` will make them equal but I cannot change the **SQL** Statement, I need to change it on the **PHP** calculation.

> How do I change the function date('W',strtotime($data)) so It gives me a week equal to SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can't change the query, you'd have to exactly replicate php's week calculation yourself. e.g. roll your own.

Comment: Ok, I though that PHP could have something to change the definition of the function to make them equal to the SQL one like the SQL have one to mimic the PHP one but I never found it.

Comment: nope. there' just date('W'), which is iso8601-compliant.

Comment: try this... `strftime(%V, strtotime($mydate))` also you can try changing the %V to %U

Comment: If the problem is just one day, try to use date('o') and date('w') to understand in wich day and wich YEAR you are, and adjust the weeknumber by yourself.

Comment: strftime(%U, strtotime($mydate)) It worked thanks!

Comment: @Condward I added my comment as an answer for so you can accept it :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try something like this in php

```
strftime(%U, strtotime($mydate))
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't change how PHP calculates week numbers.
2. You should not attempt to "roll your own" week calculation. Date math is hella complex.

The *best* solution would be to alter the query to use `WEEK(mydate, 3)`, but failing that you should offload the calculation to the same MySQL server as you're retrieveing the other week data from:

```
$example_date = '2014-12-16';
$query = sprintf("SELECT WEEK('%s')", $example_date);
if( ! $res = $dbh->query($query) ) { die('fission mailed'); }
$val = $res->fetch();
printf("Week number: %d\n", $val[0]);
// Week number: 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_week_format

If you can't change the query itself, you could change that variable. (Although you might not be able to, if you can't change the query).